# Execute an embeded exe with createprocess c++

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to execute an exe file which is embedded in a buffer. I try to execute this exe file with createProcess (i think that this is possible) but i get the createprocess error 123.

Here is the code:

```
void main(){

unsigned char exe_file[] = {
  0x4d, 0x5a, 0x90, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00...
}

STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    if (!CreateProcess((LPCWSTR)exe_file,   // No module name (use command line)
        NULL,        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
        )
    {
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);



}
```

I add the LPCWSTR casting because if not, I get a compilation error (incompatibility of unsigned char...)
Thank you.

Comment: If you're asking about C++ code, as the title indicates, do not include the C tag too (and vice versa).  It annoys people and may earn you downvotes.

Comment: why do you think you should be able to pass machine code as the first argument of CreateProcess

Comment: you have to write it to temp disk file , then run it

Comment: Also, why is your embedded EXE in a byte array directly in the code, and not stored in a data resource instead?

Comment: Casting a byte buffer to a string pointer does not have magical powers. All you did was tell the compiler to treat the bytes as if they were a string. (Spoiler alert: They probably don't form a useful string.)

Comment: _I add the LPCWSTR casting_ That never, ever, works.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the array is an embedded malware exe. It has to be embedded (it is one of the requirements). Then I want to use CreateProcess to execute it. This is for uploading the resulting exe to VirusTotal and check the detections as I am trying a method for evading malware sandboxes. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm sorry. I have just started using stack overflow to post questions.

Comment: It's OK — that's why I commented (and removed the extraneous tag) rather than downvoting.  Remember for the future.  Do not include both the C and C++ tags unless you question is, in some way, about the interworking of the two languages.

Answer (score 5):

> I try to execute this exe file [which is embedded in a buffer] with createProcess (i think that this is possible)

Sorry, but no, it is not possible with `CreateProcess()`. It works only with `.EXE` files on disk, not in memory. You would have to save your buffer to a temporary file first, and then execute that file instead.

Otherwise, there are 3rd party loaders floating around that support running EXE images from memory buffers.  There is nothing in the native Win32 API that supports what you are attempting.